# Pass the QAction object which calls triggered.connect() as a parameter in the function that is triggered after i click on QAction

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt4, signals-slots

i am creating list of QAction objects using for loop like this:

```
class some_class:
  self.tabs = []

  for self.i in range(0,10):
    self.tabs[self.i] = QtGui.QAction("New", self)
    self.tabs[self.i].triggered.connect(self.some_function)

  def some_function(self):
    print self.i
```

whenever i click on any of the tabs created, it triggers only tabs[9] and print "9" only.

So how to pass the QAction object itself in the some_function which triggered some_function()

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cache the index as a default argument:

```
for index in range(0, 10):
    action = QtGui.QAction("New", self)
    action.triggered.connect(
        lambda checked, index=index: self.some_function(index))
    self.tabs.append(action)

...

def some_function(self, index):
    action = self.tabs[index]
    print(action.text())
```

Comment: action.triggered.connect(
        lambda *args, index=index: self.some_function(index))

produce syntax error

Comment: @SahilGupta. It works fine for me. No errors of any kind. You must have changed my code somehow. What is the syntax error?

Comment: It works with action.triggered.connect( lambda : self.some_function(index)) & also with ( lambda *args: self.some_function(index))  but creates syntax error with  
action.triggered.connect( lambda *args, index=index: self.some_function(index)). Thanks for telling about using lambda function.

Comment: @SahilGupta. It must be because you are using python2, so it's not possible to have `*args` before a keyword argument. I've updated my answer so that it should work with both python2 and python3.

Comment: File "test_tabs.py", line 33
    self.tabs_action[index].triggered.connect(lambda *args, index=index:self.show_tab(index))
                                                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: This Worked, but why is it working without "checked, index=index" also

Comment: @SahilGupta. It **doesn't** work without that. If you leave out `index=index`, the same index (`9`) will be sent each time.

Comment: Wow, powerful magic: if the name of the slot's parameter is changed to something other than `index`, this doesn't work: it then always returns the last value of `index` in the loop (which would be 9 in your example).

Comment: @mikerodent All uses of the argument name in the `lambda` must be the same, otherwise the default argument would be redundant - i.e. `lambda checked, FOO=index: self.some_function(FOO))`.